# Prevent function running for lots of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the misleading title its hard to explain!

Basically I have a function that when you click left/right a div moves X pixels either way.

```
// Upcoming events slide 
$('.nextEvent').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.newsColWrap').offset().left == '597.5'){

    } else {
        $('.newsColWrap').stop(true,true).animate({'left' : "-=435px"},500)
    }
});
$('.prevEvent').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.newsColWrap').offset().left == '1032.5'){

    } else {
        $('.newsColWrap').stop(true,true).animate({'left' : "+=435px"},500);
    }
});
```

The function works fine, but if the animations is happening and you click again, because the if statement doesn't return my div moves too far, does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the element is being animated using **[`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)** before animating it again.

```
$('.nextEvent').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).is(':animated')) return; // check if currently being animated
    // ... animate
});

$('.prevEvent').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).is(':animated')) return; // check if currently being animated
    // ... animate
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you are reading the offset before the previous animation is completed so try

```
$('.nextEvent').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $newsColWrap = $('.newsColWrap').stop(true, true);
    if ($newsColWrap.offset().left == '597.5') {

    } else {
        $newsColWrap.animate({
            'left': "-=435px"
        }, 500)
    }
});
$('.prevEvent').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $newsColWrap = $('.newsColWrap').stop(true, true);
    if ($newsColWrap.offset().left == '1032.5') {

    } else {
        $newsColWrap.stop(true, true).animate({
            'left': "+=435px"
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun, this still allows me to carry on clicking however and move the div far right?

Comment: @Liam in that case try techfoobar's answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple setTimeout function running for 500.